# ¿Cómo crear una función que me sume las observaciones de una variable dada una condición en otra variable?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, funciones, dataframe, función-personalizada

Dado este data frame (df)

```
state   county   population
   <chr>   <chr>         <dbl>
 1 Alabama Autauga       55221
 2 Alabama Baldwin      195121
 3 Alabama Barbour       26932
 4 Alabama Bibb          22604
 5 Alabama Blount        57710
 6 Alabama Bullock       10678
 7 Alabama Butler        20354
 8 Alabama Calhoun      116648
 9 Alabama Chambers      34079
10 Alabama Cherokee      26008
# ... with 3,128 more rows
```

Quiero crear una función que me sume la población total dado un Estado

```
Poblacion_por_Estado<-function(datos,estado){
  
  count<-0
  
  for(i in 1:nrow(datos)){
    if(datos[i,1]!="estado"){
      next
    }
    count<-count+datos[i,3]
    
  }
  return(count)
}

Poblacion_por_Estado(df,California)
```

Soy bastante nuevo en R y no sé que estoy haciendo mal, pero me devuelve 0.
Sé que esto sale de una manera muy fácil con la paquetería dplyr, pero quiero aprender a declarar mis propias funciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error está aquí:

```
if(datos[i,1]!="estado")
```

Estás comparando cada valor de `state` o más bien la primer columna de `datos` con la cadena literal `estado`, deberías usar el parámetro de la función más bien:

```
if (datos[i,1] != estado)
```

Y la invocación, debiera ser así:

```
Poblacion_por_Estado(df, "California")
```

Nota las comillas que encierran `California`.

No puedo dejar de comentarte que este enfoque iterativo, que es habitual en la mayoría de los lenguajes, es totalmente innecesario en R. R es lenguaje que solo sabe de datos vectoriales, toda la lógica y sintaxis está enfocada a esto. Por lo que hacer lo que buscas, de la manera  natural, sería algo así:

```
Poblacion_por_Estado <- function(datos,estado){
   sum(datos[datos$state == estado, 3))
}
```